# Sending void* in structure over linux sockets

Tags: linux, sockets

I want to send a void * in a structure over socket.
My structure:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    void * vptr;
};
```

client side

```
struct A a;
struct B b;

// filling structure B
 .....

// filling structure A
a.i = 1;
a.vptr = &b
write(servsocket,(char*)&a,sizeof(struct A));
```

But at the server side when i m reading the structure and typecasting void * into another srtucture segmentation fault comes.

Server side

```
struct A *a;
stuct B *b;
char recvBuff[1024];
read(sock,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff));
a= (A*)recvBuff;
printf("%d",a->i);   // printing value 1
b = (B*)a->vptr;    // segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

> But at the server side when i m reading the structure and typecasting
>   void * into another srtucture segmentation fault comes.

The pointer only makes sense in the address space where it originated, i.e. in process A. It is only an address, something like 4 bytes. When you move it to a different process (possibly a different machines) **that address will no longer make any sense**.

So you need to somehow transfer the actual object, not just a pointer to it.

Comment: As per my requirements i have to send a void * only. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have done it! But result of using vptr on server side is undefined behavior. If you actually want to get B on server side you should transfer it with A.